# When loading indexes in elasticsearch, I seem to be hitting a physical limit?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I've loaded an index which contained 28.7million records, but only 18.4million were loaded. No errors have been reported in either logstash (used to load the data) or in Elasticsearch. I've tried to load the same file again, but it only managed to load 4.5K records. Again no errors have been found.

I've deleted all three indexes created and tried to once again load the file, but this time, it isn't loading any documents! Therefore it is safe to assume that I am hitting a physical limit of Elasticsearch, but I cannot find out where and what this limit is.

My server is a dual core Xeon backed up with 8GB of memory. I have 140GB of disk space free. The elasticsearch config file has not been touched since the install.

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly a case of heap exhaustion. I think the default heap size is 1 GB and I wouldn't expect that to be even nearly enough for 30 M documents. See a [recent logstash-users thread](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/logstash-users/uzf-5t1_-g0/discussion) talking about a seemingly identical problem with an elaboration on how Elasticsearch uses its heap.

For an 8 GB system, 4 GB would be a good heap size. You can adjust the JVM heap size in e.g. /etc/default/elasticsearch (Debian-based systems) or /etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch (RPM-based systems).

Comment: Thanks Magnus. Since my original question, I deleted the three indexes to see if I would hit the original limit again, but now I cannot load anything using logstash. I will try and up the heap and see what happens.